Valid node is not enough
Start a single-node service and connect the service to write data. Will report an error:Valid node is not enough, need: 1, but found: 0
version:cnosdb 2.4.1, revision 9b25565
deploy:singleton
I tried it many times and found that this happened by accident.
I encountered this problem by following the steps below:

start the server:

docker run -d --name dfosssi-main -p 12007:8902 -v /data/DF_OSS_SI_main/conf/:/etc/cnosdb/ -v /data/DF_OSS_SI_main/data/:/var/  cnosdb/cnosdb:community-latest-20240627 cnosdb run -c 8 -m 32 --config /etc/cnosdb/cnosdb.conf -M singleton

2.  create table and  insert the data:
cnosdb-cli -P 12007
CnosDB CLI v2.3.0
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 12007, user: "root", password: None, private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, precision: None }
public ❯ CREATE TABLE air001 (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,pressure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));
Query took 0.004 seconds.
public ❯
INSERT INTO air001 (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES (1667456411000000000, 'XiaoMaiDao1', 56, 69, 411);
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030053","error_message":"Valid node is not enough, need: 1, but found: 0"}

Stack backtrace:
   0: anyhow::error::<impl anyhow::Error>::msg
   1: anyhow::__private::format_err
   2: client::ctx::SessionContext::sql::{{closure}}
   3: client::exec::exec_and_print::{{closure}}
   4: client::exec::exec_from_repl::{{closure}}
   5: cnosdb_cli::main::{{closure}}
   6: cnosdb_cli::main
   7: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
   8: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
   9: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:287:13
  10: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:487:40
  11: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:451:19
  12: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  13: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
  14: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:487:40
  15: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:451:19
  16: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  17: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
  18: main
  19: __libc_start_main
             at /usr/src/debug/glibc-2.17-c758a686/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:266
  20: <unknown>

Add some config information:
[global]
node_id = 1001
host = "dfosssi-main"
cluster_name = 'cluster_xxx'
store_metrics = true


[deployment]
# mode = 'query_tskv'
# cpu = 8
# memory = 16

[meta]
service_addr = ["127.0.0.1:8901"]
report_time_interval = "30s"

[query]
max_server_connections = 10240
query_sql_limit = "16777216B"  # 16 * 1024 * 1024
write_sql_limit = "167772160B" # 160 * 1024 * 1024
auth_enabled = false
read_timeout = "300000ms"
write_timeout = "300000ms"
stream_trigger_cpu = 1
stream_executor_cpu = 2
sql_record_timeout = "10s"

[storage]
path = '/var/lib/cnosdb/data'
strict_write = false

max_datablock_size = "100KB"

[wal]
enabled = true
path = '/var/lib/cnosdb/wal'


[cache]


[log]
level = 'info'
path = '/var/log/cnosdb'
[security]
# [security.tls_config]
# certificate = "/etc/config/tls/server.crt"
# private_key = "/etc/config/tls/server.key"

[service]
http_listen_port = 8902
grpc_listen_port = 8903
grpc_enable_gzip = false
flight_rpc_listen_port = 8904
tcp_listen_port = 8905
vector_listen_port = 8906
enable_report = true


[cluster]
# raft_logs_to_keep = 5000
# using_raft_replication = false

[hinted_off]
enable = true
path = '/var/lib/cnosdb/hh'
threads = 3

This is different from the problem . This problem has been fixed. The error message returned is incorrect.
Has anyone encountered similar problems? The recurrence here is also unstable, and I don't know why it is like this here.

This question is similar to: Both nodes on my side are cold nodes, but the return information:Valid node is not enough, need: 1, but found: 1. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Luuk Thanks for your reminder, I added some information and I found the cause of the problem

Maybe you can have a try on V2.4.2 https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/releases/tag/v2.4.2

I later modified the configuration file and found that the problem was solved.
host = "localhost"

I wonder if this is a problem where address resolution is not configured locally?
